# Set relationship between Big-Oh and Theta notations

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

I was reading "**Introduction to Algorithms**" by CLRS and it says that:

> We write *$f(n) = O(g(n))$* to indicate that a function *$f(n)$* is a member of of the set *$O(g(n))$*. Note that *$f(n) = \Theta(g(n))$* implies *$f(n)=O(g(n))$*, since $\Theta$-notation is a stronger notion than *$O$* notation. Written set-theoretically, we have *$\Theta(g(n)) \subseteq O(g(n))$*.

Q1: What do the authors mean by *strong notion*? What is *strong notion*, when we use it, how does it help us (here) knowing one implication is stronger than the other and how does it affect when creating implication.

Q2: It seems contradictory in a sense by saying that *$\Theta$* is stronger notion than *$O$* and then writing $\Theta(g(n)) \subseteq O(g(n))$.How to deduce and then interpret the second sentence from the first?

I would appreciate your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, a proposition $P$ is said to be *stronger* than $Q$ if $P$ implies $Q$ ( symbolically, $P\Rightarrow Q$)  and $NOT$( $Q$ implies $P$).  In the example at hand, $f \in \Theta(g) \Rightarrow f \in \mathcal{O}(g)$ , so that $f \in \Theta(g)$ is a stronger assertion than $f \in \mathcal{O}(g)$.

Answer (score 1):

When you say $f(n) = \mathcal{O}(g(n))$, it means that $g$ is an upper bound for $f$, up to a constant. So $f(n) \leq c \cdot g(n)$ for all $n \geq k$, and for some $c_1$. $c_1$ and $k$ are fixed. Now we must introduce $\Omega$. If $f(n) = \Omega(g(n))$, then $g$ is a lower bound for $f$, up to a constant. So $f(n) \geq c_2\cdot g(n)$.

Now, when we say $f(n) = \Theta(g(n))$, then $f \in \mathcal{O}(g(n))$ and $f \in \Omega(g(n))$. So $\Theta$ is a *tight* bound, while $\mathcal{O}$ is only an upper bound. Thats what is means by stronger.
$f \in \Theta(g) \iff c_2\cdot g <= f <= c_1\cdot g$. When the author says $\Theta(g(n)) \subseteq \mathcal{O}(g(n))$, they mean that whenever $f \in \Theta(g)$, $f$ is also in $\mathcal{O}(g)$

Another thing worth noting is that a lot of people assume we only use $\mathcal{O}$ for worst case analysis and $\Omega$ for best case. This is not the case. A tight bound is much more useful. Usually, use both of them (as in use $\Theta$) for both best case and worst case (and average case) analysis.

Answer (score 0):

"stronger notation" from first sentence simply means subset from second - it is same.